# The DOM is loading but is not displayed without clicking on screen mobile Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a very strange problem that I really don't know how to solve.
When I'm on my mobile, my page loads as follows [homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwkNG.png)

But when you click on the screen all the components appear.
Can I generate a fake click on my mobile or something?
I really have no idea what's going on
I would also check how the scripts load, I have nothing to do with async defer
Do you think that a fake click would solve me?

For example, when it loads its page to click / touch on the mobile?

Answer (score 0):

You have to selected an element and then you can call click()

```js
document.getElementById('yourelement').click()
```

This should go on your `mounted()` default layout.